# ffmpeg get list of all allowed extensions

Tags: ffmpeg

community.
 I need help.
 I try to capture screen using ffmpeg.
 I could be show you my command that i use to capture screen, but i think that it doesn't matter.
  How can i get list of all allowed output file extensions? Any suggestions?
If solution for me already exists, sorry me.
For ex i will show you small part of list witch i wanna get:

```
mp4, .mp4v, .avi, .mov....
```

I haven't tried anything.

Thank you:)

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does capturing the screen have to do with extensions? What do you mean by "allowed extensions"?

Comment: @llogan, that's my command
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -c:v libx264 output.mkv.
I can replace "output.mkv" to "out.mp4" or to "out.avi", however i can't replace "output.mkv" to "out.txt". How can i get list of all allowed output file extensions witch i can add after "output."?

Comment: What is the reason you need to list supported extensions? There is no list of supported extensions, but you can list muxers. See [What are all codecs and formats supported by FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20587693/)